# Listview inside scrollview page appear bottom

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am creating a new project where I am using a listview inside a scroll view.But I got an issue where when I open this page by default 
it goes to the bottom of the page where I set my listview.
But my requirement is that When I open the page it should show the top of the page..pls help me..

my xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.test.Product_description"
>
<!--android:background="@drawable/bg_products"-->

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ccffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_proDesc_mainImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                 />
           <!-- android:background="@drawable/to_be_deleted_1"-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_proDesc_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="$ 9.95"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="28dp" />
            <!--android:background="@drawable/bg_price"-->
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_proDesc_productName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Premium Cherry Soup"
            android:textColor="#d58001"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_proDesc_productDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book." />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_proDesc_wishlist"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"

                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Wishlist"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
           <!-- android:background="@drawable/btn_wishlist"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/heart"-->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_proDesc_addtocart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"

                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:includeFontPadding="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Add to Cart"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <!--android:background="@drawable/btn_addtocart"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cart"-->
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:text="Reviews"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:translationZ="10dp" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rB_proDesc_rating"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="6"
            android:rating="4"
            android:stepSize="1" />
        <!--style="@style/foodRatingBar"-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lL_proDesc_userReviews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listcomment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            >

            </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why your are wrapping `ListView` in `ScrollView`?

Comment: Yes listview inside scrollview

Comment: but why ? because `ListView` is already scrollable

Comment: no..i am doing a restaurant app..my page consist of product description and at the bottom comments and reviews..this is what i put inside a listview

Comment: so the whole page is not a list view

Comment: Then make scrollable part as listview and make other static

Comment: post your xml so We can improve or suggest you

Comment: i posted my xml...plz check

Comment: On thing is you can do it by `desing-libaray` and `CordinatorLayout` see this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: see @Delargo answer it will work for you

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32816390/3758898

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ListView inside the scrollview. That means you have to give height of listview after set adapter

For Exe

```
Listview.setAdapter(adapter);
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview, adapter);

public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView,StaffManagerJobDetailListAdapter staffmgrJobDetailsAdapter) {
    if(staffmgrJobDetailsAdapter==null){
        return;
    }       
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int items = staffmgrJobDetailsAdapter.getCount();
    if(items==0){
        totalHeight = 0;
    }else{
        totalHeight = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_50dp)*(items-candidateJobProfileDetails.size()));

    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight+(listView.getDividerHeight() * (items - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.setFocusable(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only `ListView` instead. You can add top part of your xml to the header of `ListView`.

First, create header.xml with top part of your xml without `ScrollView` and `ListView`.

Second, in my.xml remain only `ListView`.

Then in your activity's `onCreate()` write down follow:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listcomment);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
listView.addHeader(header);
CommentAdapter adapter = new CommentAdapter();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that when you open the page, the `ScrollView` page should show top of page, then you should programmatically scroll to top of page when page resumes.

```
ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
mainScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ExpandableHeightListView](https://gist.github.com/Kishanjvaghela/248b86b9e1c9fbcb8cd7) instead of ListView.