# Pass motion event to parent Scrollview when Listview at top/bottom

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, motionevent

I have a `ListView` in a `ScrollView` to show comments and I would like to do the following:

When the user swipes down, first the `ScrollView` should fully scroll down as the list is at the bottom. Once it's fully down, the `Listiew` should start scrolling.

Similarly, when the user is scrolling up, first the `ListView` (order reversed here!) should scroll up, before the `ScrollView` starts scrolling.

So far I have done the following:

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside ScrollView
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // If going up but the list is already at up, return false indicating we did not consume it.
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (listView.getChildCount() == 0 && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0) {
                    Log.e("Listview", "At top!");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Similar behaviour but when going down check if we are at the bottom.
            if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1 &&
                        listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
                    Log.e("Listview","At bottom!");
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The logs trigger at the right moment, however the `ScrollView` won't move even though I return false.

I also tried to add `v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);` to the statements, but that did not work either.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I've tried doing this (nesting a listview in my scrollview) and I couldn't get it to work. I ended up using two NestedScrollView

Comment: I looked at the NestedScrollView class too, but as pointed at on other threads listviews do have some additional functions over for example a LinearLayout inside a scrollview

Comment: Generally I would recommend using a header view in a ListView, instead of nesting a ListView inside a ScrollView - Nested scroll containers pre-RecyclerView is somewhat painful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom `ScrollView` and `ListView` and override

```
onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));

    if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (diff ==0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This way every Down Touch on the `ListView` while you are at the bottom of `ScrollView` will go to the `ListView`.

This is just a sketch implementation but I think you could get started from this by doing the same thing to detect when you are at the top of the `ListView`

As a note I would try an easier implementation by using just a `ListView` with the current content of you `ScrollView` added as the header of ListView by using `listView.addHeaderView(scrollViewContent)`. I don't know if this fits your needs.

EDIT:

Detecting when should start scrolling the `ScrollView`. Keeping a reference of `ListView` in the `ScrollView`. When the user is scrolling up and the the `ListView` is at the top let the event be consumed by the `ScrollView`.

```
private void init(){
    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
    mTouchSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            yPrec = event.getY();
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final float dy = event.getY() - yPrec;

            if (dy > mTouchSlop) {
                // Start scrolling!
                mIsScrolling = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mIsScrolling = false;
    }

    // Calculate the scrolldiff
    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));

        if ((!mIsScrolling || !listViewReference.listIsAtTop()) && diff == 0) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                return false;
            }
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mIsScrolling = false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}


public void setListViewReference(MyListView listViewReference) {
    this.listViewReference = listViewReference;
}
```

The method listIsAtTop in ListView looks like this :

```
public boolean listIsAtTop()   {
    if(getChildCount() == 0) return true;
    return (getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0 && getFirstVisiblePosition() ==0);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is a circular dependency between the listview and the scrollview. I tried implementing something with the touch intercept method, but as the order is reversed when scrolling up, the scrollview has to "check" if the listview is done first.

Comment: Check out my edit to the answer. I made a test and it works but i am not sure this is what you are trying to achieve. You just have to set a reference to the listview in the scrollview. The code may require some extra tweaking and clean up.

Answer (score 4):

You should not put ListView inside ScrollView, but you can achieve your requirement by using [ExpandableHeightListView](https://gist.github.com/Kishanjvaghela/248b86b9e1c9fbcb8cd7). This will make full height Listview inside ScrollView. No need add TouchListener.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
             <!-- your content -->
        </RelativeLayout>

        <my.widget.ExpandableHeightListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And another way to achieve your requirement is [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with header.

Comment: While it does work, it is not really what I asked. This just shows all the items below the content, might as well throw views inside a LinearLayout then.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

1. First find if you reached at scrollview Bottom. Register the onScrollChanged to your Scroll view

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) 
   {
       // Grab the last child placed in the ScrollView, we need it to determinate the bottom position.
       View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);

       // Calculate the scrolldiff
       int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));

       // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
       if( diff == 0 )
       {
           // notify that we have reached the bottom
           // Add code here to start scrolling the ListView
           Log.d(ScrollTest.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached" );
       }

       super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
   }
   ```
2. Check if you reach at the Top of ListView. Check if firstVisibleItem is 0:-

   ```
   tableListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

           public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

           }

           public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                   int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
               if (visibleItemCount == 0)
               // you have reached at top of lustView
               {
                   java.lang.System.out.println("you have reached at top of lustView!");
               }
               else {
                   if ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount) {
                       // put your stuff here
                       java.lang.System.out.println("end of the line reached!");
                   }
               }

           }
       });
   ```

I hope this works for you. If face any issues, please let me know.

Comment: Detecting if I reached the top or bottom is what my code already does, I want however to pass motion events to the parent scrollview depending on this state.