# ListView in BottomSheet not scrolling

Tags: android-layout, listview, bottom-sheet

Writing for Android API 23 and above (testing on API 24 and 25).

I have written an XML which attempts to put a ListView inside of a BottomSheet. When I attempt to scroll my ListView (in any direction) the BottomSheet scrolls rather than the ListView.

I've tried the following workaround without any success:

> [ListView in BottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570985/listview-in-bottomsheet)

My XML layout file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onButtonPress"
                android:text="@string/refresh_button" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="Stations"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <com.example.nicsutherland.stationfinder.Adapters.BottomSheetListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My java class contains the following code in the onCreate() method:

```
View bottomSheet = findViewById( R.id.bottom_sheet );
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(300);
```

How can I get to a point where my ListView will scroll independently of my BottomSheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
com.example.nicsutherland.stationfinder.Adapters.BottomSheetListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"\\insert this line
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the BottomSheetDialog Cancelable false and CanceledOnTouchOutside true

```
 bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false);


 bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);